# C# extension method compilation / compatibility checks failing based on order of namespaces

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I am writing two extension methods. One to work on a single object, and another to work on a collection of objects. When calling the extension method, the C# compiler seems to get confused as to which one to use, and fails compilation.

More surprisingly, if I move the extension methods to different namespaces, even if I include both namespaces in the callsite, compilation only fails if the namespaces are in a particular order alphabetically - switching the namespaces causes compilation to succeed.

Here is the code:

```
public static class DBObjectExtensions
{
    public static void PopulateRelations<T>(this T obj, params RelationToPrefetch[] relationsToPrefetch) where T : IDBObject
    {
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        obj.Transaction.PopulateRelations<T>(new[]{ obj }, relationsToPrefetch);
    }

    public static void PopulateRelations<T>(this IEnumerable<T> objects, params RelationToPrefetch[] relationsToPrefetch) where T : IDBObject
    {
        var first = objects.FirstOrDefault();
        if (first == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        first.Transaction.PopulateRelations<T>(objects, relationsToPrefetch);
    }
}
```

This is the callsite line that fails compilation:

```
List<ITable> list = ... // ITable inherits from IDBObject
list.PopulateRelations(xxx);
```

Fails with error CS0311:

> The type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Granta.MI.DBObjectExtensions.PopulateRelations(T, params Granta.MI.RelationToPrefetch[])'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'Granta.MI.IDBObject'.

Note that this line succeeds compilation if I delete the 2nd extension method.

Also note that writing trampoline methods (for every possible type of collection...) also works:

```
public static void PopulateRelations<T>(this List<T> objects, params RelationToPrefetch[] relationsToPrefetch) where T : IDBObject
{
    ((IEnumerable<T>)objects).PopulateRelations(relationsToPrefetch);
}

public static void PopulateRelations<T>(this IList<T> objects, params RelationToPrefetch[] relationsToPrefetch) where T : IDBObject
{
    ((IEnumerable<T>)objects).PopulateRelations(relationsToPrefetch);
}
```

Why can't the compiler figure out there is a matching extension method? And more confusingly, if I put one of the methods in a different namespace, and I include that namespace, why does compilation then succeed? Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: Overload resolution doesn't take constraints into account. Furthermore, you don't seem to need `T` inside the method function, why do you need to use `T` for your extension instead of just using `IDbObject`?

Comment: @Jcl people get confused very often with the use of `T`, as you said if you don't need `T`  inside the extension method just simply change the methods like in the @jakub-lortz answer.

Comment: Apologies - I didn't include the reason for not doing that in my answer. The reason is that `Transaction.PopulateRelations` also takes a type T and then calls `typeof` so I need that T to be a concrete type not just `IDBObject`.

Answer (score 2):

Generic constraints are not part of the method signature, so the compiler choose `PopulateRelations<T>(this T obj, params RelationToPrefetch[] relationsToPrefetch)` because `T` is more derived than `IEnumerable<T>`.

Example, between these 2 methods:

```
public static void PopulateRelations(this List<ITable> obj, params RelationToPrefetch[] relationsToPrefetch)
{
    // Do something
}

public static void PopulateRelations(this IEnumerable<ITable> objects, params RelationToPrefetch[] relationsToPrefetch)
{
    // Do something
}
```

The first one is chosen when calling:

```
List<ITable> list;
PopulateRelations(list, something); // Not calling as extension method to more clear
```

Because `list` matches directly with `List<ITable>`

Comment: Eric Lippert wrote a useful blog post related to this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature.aspx

Comment: So why did compilation then succeed when I reorder the namespaces?

Comment: @MichaelParker how do you order namespaces?

Comment: If method A is in the same namespace as the calling code and method B is in a different namespace, then compilation fails. If i then switch the methods so method A is now in a different namespace and the 2nd is now in the same namespace as the calling code, compilation succeeds.

Comment: When you move method A in a different namespace, do you do `using ThatNamespaceName;`

Answer (score 0):

Your generic types are constrained to IDBObject, so you could just make the extension methods non-generic:

```
public static void PopulateRelations(this IDBObject obj, params RelationToPrefetch[] relationsToPrefetch)
{
    //...
}

public static void PopulateRelations(this IEnumerable<IDBObject> objects, params RelationToPrefetch[] relationsToPrefetch)
{
    //...
}
```

It solves the compilation error.

Comment: Not quite, because they are delegating to a generic method on transaction called PopulateRelations which uses the T and calls `typeof` on T.  I realise I didn't include this in my original post - apologies.